# Pinescript - Use series for EMA

Tags: pine-script

I wonder if its possible to do but I'm trying to create an EMA whose length depends on ATR, so as ATR increases, the EMA gets wider and slower. Here's what I have,

```
study(title="ATR + EMA", shorttitle="ATR+EMA", overlay=true, resolution="")
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
atrLength = input(title="ATR Length", type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1)

atrLine = atr(atrLength)
out = ema(src, atrLine)

plot(atr, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)
```

But that gives me an error that the length of ema should be integer, not series. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [ema()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_ema) and [sma()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_sma) don't support dynamic length.
Several [other functions](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/more-pine-functions-support-dynamic-length-arguments-22719/) do support dynamic lengths.

In the meantime, you could use the `pine_sma()` and `pine_ema()` functions that are given in the examples in the reference manual on those functions.

Like this:

```
//@version=4
study(title="ATR + EMA", shorttitle="ATR+EMA", overlay=true, resolution="")

len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
atrLength = input(title="ATR Length", type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1)

pine_sma(x, y) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1
        sum := sum + x[i] / y
    sum
    
pine_ema(src, length) =>
    p_sma = pine_sma(src, length)
    alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? p_sma : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

atrLine = atr(atrLength)
out = pine_ema(src, atrLine)

plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.yellow, offset=offset)
```

Comment: The built-in sma() does support series length, only ema() doesn't.

Comment: How would this be converted to JavaScript or psuedo code? `sum` being declared as 0.0 (a float) and then the rest of the code checking index 1 `sum[1]` is confusing. When did it go from float to a series? I would expect `src[1]` because src is a series but... that's not what it says.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what has been said above, it's important to note that the EMA algorithm uses its own values on previous bars for its calculation (unlike SMA, that can be properly calculated on each bar without referring to the past SMA values). This means that the EMA with a series length will not behave in a way you might expect, it's inherently different. For example, this code compares two SMAs with non-series length to an SMA with a variable length, and they will be equal:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
cond = bar_index % 2 == 0
sma5 = sma(close, 5)
sma10 = sma(close, 10)
smaseries = sma(close, cond ? 5 : 10)
plot(smaseries)
plot(cond ? sma5 : sma10)
```

This code compares EMAs in a similar fashion. They'll be noticeably different due to what I described above:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
cond = bar_index % 2 == 0
ema5 = ema(close, 5)
ema10 = ema(close, 10)
pine_ema(src, length) =>
    p_sma = sma(src, length)
    alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? p_sma : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])
emaseries = pine_ema(close, cond ? 5 : 10)
plot(emaseries)
plot(cond ? ema5 : ema10)
```